# torch row wise cosinus similarity

Tags: pytorch

Assuming I am having 2 tensors with dimension:

- tensor A: `[512, 100]`
- tensor B: `[512, 200, 100]`

and I would like to use `torch.cosine_similarity` to produce a tensor C of dimensions `[512, 1, 200]` or `[512, 200]`.

Using `torch.cosine_similarity(A, B)` I get an error:

'*{RuntimeError}The size of tensor a (512) must match the size of tensor b (200) at non-singleton dimension 1*'

I guess it can be done by the following:

```
desired_result = torch.stack([torch.cosine_similarity(A_row, B_row, axis=-1) for B_row, A_row in zip(B, A)])
```

but there should be a more optimized way. Any help/hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for stacking, broadcasting will do the job for you:

```
# (512, 100, 1) after unsqueeze
A = torch.randn(512, 100).unsqueeze(dim=-1)
B = torch.randn(512, 200, 100)

# (512, 200)
torch.cosine_similarity(B, A.unsqueeze(1), axis=-1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and my apologies as I have missclicked the dimensions of tensor B. I have edited my question.

Comment: your answer helped. it was `torch.cosine_similarity(B, A.unsqueeze(1), axis=-1)`. Update the answer to accept it, in case some other people come up to it. thanks

Comment: @MpizosDimitris Sorry, was AFK, glad you solved your issue, updated the answer.